# CosmosDBInput binding of Azure Function is not using path Variable defined in HttpTrigger

Tags: java, kotlin, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-java-sdk

I have created a function with Kotlin using azure-functions-kotlin-archetype. I have created a Http Trigger and a cosmos input binding to read data from the cosmos. I have mentioned sql query also to fetch the data. I want to pass path variable to the http trigger which should be used as parameter in the query.
As per Microsoft documentation I have defined the path parameter accordingly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=java#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-from-route-data-using-sqlquery-java

But I am getting blank response, means no data is fetched. If I hard code the parameter in the Sql query, I able to fetch the data. Can any one please tell me the issue here. The Function Code is as below

```
@FunctionName("GetData")
    fun run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                    name = "req",
                    methods = [HttpMethod.GET],
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
            route = "/api/getItems/{id}/{qnt}"
            )
            request: HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>>,
            @CosmosDBInput(
                name = "cosmosdb",
                databaseName = "item-db",
                collectionName = "item",
                sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ITEM n where n.id= {id} "
                             +"and n.qnt = {qnt}",
              connectionStringSetting = "Cosmos_DB_Connection_String"
            )
            rs: Array<String>,
            context: ExecutionContext): HttpResponseMessage {



            return request
                    .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .body(rs)
                    .build()
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi, may I know if you still use `route` when you request function with hard code sqlQuery ?

Comment: @HuryShen Yes, I use route always. No change except instead of taking value from route, I hard coded it.

Comment: Ok, I will test it in my side. Could you please have a try to remove the `/` before `api/getItems/{id}/{qnt}` in your `route` ?

Comment: @HuryShen Thats a mistake in the typing, the / infront of api is not present in the actual code.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the value of `id` and `qnt`, also please provide a sample of `sqlQuery` when you request it hard code.

Comment: Sample Query: SELECT * FROM ITEM n where n.id= {'ID1'} "
                             +"and n.qnt = {1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sample query you provided: `SELECT * FROM ITEM n where n.id= {'ID1'} " +"and n.qnt = {1}`, it seems the `id` is string and `qnt` is a number. When we get the parameters from `route`, it will treat the parameters as string. So if you use the parameters from `route` in `sqlQuery` directly, it will select the data like this sql: `SELECT * FROM ITEM n where n.id = 'ID1' and n.qnt = '1'`. So no data is fetched.

You need to get the parameter `qnt` as a number but not as string from `route`, so please use `route = "api/getItems/{id}/{qnt:int}"`.

===========================**Update**=========================

Add this update for other communities reference:

Use the method `StringToNumber()` in sql query like `sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ITEM n where n.id= {id} " + "and n.qnt = StringToNumber({qnt})"`.

Comment: I tried mentioning data type as well, but did not work. Is it working for you using Java or Kotlin

Comment: @shoubhgh I did not test it with java. If it doesn't work in java, could you please have a try to use `sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ITEM n where n.id= {id} " + "and n.qnt = StringToNumber({qnt})"`. But I'm not sure if the method `StringToNumber()` will work in code, I just test this method in Data explorer of cosmos db.

Comment: @shoubhgh According to my test, I think the problem was caused by the type of `qnt`. But in your side, I think you can remove `and n.qnt = {qnt}` in your `sqlQuery` for a test to make sure if the problem was caused by the type of `qnt`.

Comment: StringToNumber() is the solution. You are spot on. Thanks a lot. So even though the data type is mentioned int, its still considered as String.

Comment: Hi @shoubhgh So the method `StringToNumber()` works in your code ? If it works, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~